# Download file from a django UpdateView template

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, and I've a little problem. I've a model with a FileField field, using generic views and ModelForm, I can upload a file to the server. In a modify page using an UpdateView I've a link to my document (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/static-storage/file_name),but if I try to download I get an error page not found. Maybe I need to write an url path but I can't understand how to implement. Could someone give me an help ?
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a settings misconfiguration. Please include your media files settings, `MEDIA_DIRECTORY`, `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: These are the variables:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-storage')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media-serve')

I've just set these, not MEDIA_DIRECTORY, MEDIA_URL

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the [media url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL) docs and [how to serve them in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development).